# Inline variable declaration workaround for ref parameter

Tags: c#, constructor, pass-by-reference

This is purely out of interest. I'd specifically like to know if there is a cleaner way of passing a ref int without having to create a variable.

My current workaround:

```csharp
ref stackalloc int[1] { 0 }[0]
```

And the context:

```csharp
public struct MyStruct
{
   private float x;
   private float y;
   private bool alive;

   public MyStruct(byte[] data) : this(data, ref stackalloc int[1] { 0 }[0]) { }

   public MyStruct(byte[] data, ref int index)
   {
      x = BitConverter.ToSingle(data, index); index += sizeof(float);
      y = BitConverter.ToSingle(data, index); index += sizeof(float);
      alive = BitConverter.ToBoolean(data, index); index += sizeof(bool);
   }
}
```

Constructor use context:

```csharp
MyStruct DeserializeOneStruct(byte[] data)
{
   MyStruct struct = new MyStruct (data);
   return struct;
}

List<MyStruct> DeserializeMultipleStructs(byte[] data)
{
   List<MyStruct> structList = new List<MyStruct>();

   int index = 0;
   int structCount = data[index]; index += sizeof(byte); 

   for (int i = 0; i < structCount ; i++) 
      structList.Add(new MyStruct(data, ref index));

   return structList;
}
```

Comment: You use REF so that when a method changes a value the change is also in the parent.  So I'm not sure why you are using REF in this case.  I have no idea why you would want to pass in the value one and then change one to two.

Comment: @jdweng Sometimes byte[] data contains a single 'MyStruct' and index can start from 0, sometimes its multiple and index needs to be referenced for deserialization.

Comment: @jdweng I've submitted an answer to the question. A proposal for adding inline variable declaration and discarding for ref parameters would indicate that there are currently no better ways of achieving this.

Comment: If you passed a class object than it is automatically passed ByRef.

Comment: The referenced object will be passed by value.  It will not by reference.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish as your current example doesn’t make sense.  It’s also unlikely the proposal you referenced will ever be accepted as it’s pointless.

Comment: The part that doesn’t make sense is your constructor taking the value by reference.  If you are trying something with zero allocation look at Span<> and Memory<>

Comment: @MatthewWhited I've updated the question with an extra code block for constructor context.

Comment: Even if you can, doesn't mean you should. A ref argument to a constructor is just weird. Instead you should do the least work possible, rather than faking arguments to do work that you will throw away. `MyStruct(byte[] data, ref int index) : this(data){index+=sizeof(float);}`

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Your solution only works when there is a single variable. In reality there can be many. I'll add another variable to my examples to clarify this.

Comment: Change your code to use span. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.readonlyspan-1

Answer (score -1):

It's unlikely to be the case until inline ref parameter declaration is added. A proposal has been submitted for such a thing.

[Inline variable declaration and discarding for ref parameters](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/4355)